# Generating dynamic table using jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I am using jsp to display data from oracle database. the number of column in table may change each time for different users.

I am able to retrieve column label as below:

```
rsmd = result.getMetaData();
       columns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
for (int i=1; i<=columns; i++) {
             out.write("<th>" + rsmd.getColumnLabel(i) + "</th>");
```

The connection:

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                                    String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:8081:BI";
                                    String username = "tech";
                                    String password = "****";
                                    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
                                    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
String query = "SELECT * from item_table";
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                            while (rs.next()) {
}
```

But i am facing problem in retrieving column data as the column datatypes are different. Is there any way to retrieve data without mentioning the type of "cell"?

Any input will be appreciated.

Comment: How are you trying to retrieve column date? Adding the code here would help.

Comment: You should provide us more info about what you already tried to do to solve your problem. If you don't, we won't be able to help you

Comment: @nayana I don't have date in my table.

Comment: I know this comment isn't helping the answer itself, but in the future, you generally want to stay away from java in jsp. Use something like JSTL or something

Comment: @bmarkham do you have any example suitable for above situation?

Comment: Depends. Are you using Spring?

Comment: Yes. I am using spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `getObject(int column)` method to retrieve the data as an object. Then you have not to pay attention to the data type. Afterwards you can use the `toString()` Method on this objects to display the values in your table.
[JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)

Comment: Thanks @ZeusNet. Will try and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks . it's working fine without converting to toString().